# conformal mapping onto a circular-arc bounded polygon

Tags: complex-analysis

In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269133/formula-from-w-von-koppenfels-f-stallman-praxis-der-konformen-abbildung I asked a question which turned out to be very much theoretical with references to various manuals. Here I rephrase the question and ask about a specific problem from a known problem book. Since the book seems to be available in Russian only (I think it is translated but I couldn't find a reference), I'll translate it into English:

34.26. Let $w=f(z)$ be a function conformally mapping the upper half-plane Im $z>0$ onto the domain defined by the inequalities
$$
\text{Im}\, w>0. \;\; 0<\text{Re} \, w<1, \;\; \left|w-\frac{1}{2}\right|>\frac{1}{2},
$$
so that $f(0)=0, \; f(1)=1, \; f(\infty)=\infty$. Prove that the function $f(z)$ satisfies the differential equation
$$
2\frac{f'''(z)}{f'(z)}-3\left[\frac{f''(z)}{f'(z)}\right]^2 = \frac{z^2-z+1}{z^2(z-1)^2}.
$$
Hint. See the problems 34.23 and 33.02.

The 34.23 says that the mapping function $f(z)$ analytically extends onto the whole plane save the points $0,1,\infty$, and the 33.02 says that the left-hand expression is zero on linear-fractional transformations (see f.e. Jan Krzi$\dot{z}$'s Problems in Complex Variable Theory, #7.2.14).

The problem is from the problem book "Sbornik zadach po teorii analyticheskikh functsiy" edited by Evgrafov. In his manual "Analytic functions" (available in English) Evgrafov says it can be proved so (see ch. 5, $\S$5, and ch.9, $\S$5).

Answer (score 1):

Let  $w=f(z)$ be a conformal map of the upper half-plane $H^+$ onto the domain $D$ defined by the inequalities $$
\operatorname{Im}\, w>0, \; 0<\operatorname{Re}\, w<1, \; \left|w-\frac{1}{2}\right|>\frac{1}{2}
$$
so that $f(0)=0, \; f(1)=1, \; f(\infty)=\infty$. Let $$
S_f(z)=\frac{f'''(z)}{f'(z)}-\frac{3}{2}\cdot\left[\frac{f''(z)}{f'(z)}\right]^2=\left(\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(z)}{f^\prime(z)}\right)^\prime-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(z)}{f^\prime(z)}\right)^2.$$ Then we know that $S_f(z)$ extends analytically onto the whole plane save the points $0,1.$

Let $g(z)=1-\frac{1}{f(z)}$. Then $g: H^+  \to D$ with $g(0)=\infty,\, g(1)=0,\, g(\infty)=1$. We see
$$
\frac{g^{\prime\prime}(z)}{g^\prime(z)}=\frac{-1}{z}+\text{analytic term}
$$
in some neighborhood of $z=0.$  For information on this, refer to, for instance, the equation $(3.2)$ at page $298$ in Gamelin's book. 
 Therefore $$
S_g(z)=\frac{1}{2z^2}+\frac{A}{z}+\text{analytic term}.$$
Since $S_f(z)=S_g(z)$ holds, we have $$
S_f(z)=\frac{1}{2z^2}+\frac{A}{z}+\text{analytic term}\quad (|z|<\delta ).$$
Similarly
$$
S_f(z)=\frac{1}{2(z-1)^2}+\frac{B}{z-1}+\text{analytic term}$$
in some neighborhood of $z=1$.

Thus we know that $$S_f(z)-\left\{\frac{1}{2z^2}+\frac{A}{z} +\frac{1}{2(z-1)^2}+\frac{B}{z-1} \right\}$$
is anlytic in the whole plane.
Now we determine the constants $A,B$. Note that $$S_f(z)=\frac{1}{2z^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^3}\right)\tag{1}$$ for sufficiently large $z$, so $A$ and $B$ must be $A=\frac{1}{2}$, $B=-\frac{1}{2}$.
Then $$S_f(z)-\left\{\frac{1}{2z^2}+\frac{1}{2z}+\frac{1}{2(z-1)^2}-\frac{1}{2(z-1)}\right\}$$
is analytic all over $\mathbb{C}$ and by $(1)$ 
$$S_f(z)-\left\{\frac{1}{2z^2}+\frac{1}{2z}+\frac{1}{2(z-1)^2}-\frac{1}{2(z-1)}\right\}=0,$$
which is the desired result.

Reasoning of $(1)$:  Let $h(z)=f\left(\frac{1}{1-\zeta }\right)$, which maps $H^+$ onto $D$ with $h(1)=\infty$ so $$
S_h(\zeta )=\frac{1}{2(\zeta -1)^2}+\frac{c}{\zeta -1}+\text{analytic term}.$$
We can easily check that $$
S_h(\zeta )=\left\{\left(\frac{f^{\prime\prime}\left(1/(1-\zeta )\right)}{f^\prime(1/(1-\zeta )}\right)^\prime -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{f^{\prime\prime}\left(1/(1-\zeta )\right)}{f^\prime(1/(1-\zeta )}\right)^2\right\}\cdot \frac{1}{(1-\zeta )^4}.$$ Therefore we have $$
\left(\frac{f^{\prime\prime}\left(1/(1-\zeta )\right)}{f^\prime(1/(1-\zeta )}\right)^\prime -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{f^{\prime\prime}\left(1/(1-\zeta )\right)}{f^\prime(1/(1-\zeta )}\right)^2=\frac{(1-\zeta )^2}{2}+O(1-\zeta)^3$$
for $|1-\zeta |<\delta.$ Substituting $z=1/(1-\zeta )$ we have 
$$
\left(\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(z)}{f^\prime(z)}\right)^\prime-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(z)}{f^\prime(z)}\right)^2=\frac{1}{2z^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^3}\right)\quad (|z|>R).$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Greatly appreciated